# Storing using shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am making a speedometer and want to have a top speed text view to see how quick the phone was travelling, I have tried using shared preferences but it crashes on start. I have put the shared preferences in the runnable so that it updates rapidly and checks if the current speed is higher that top speed and if it is it stores it and displays in a text view.  Thanks Ben.

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.location.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.text.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.view.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
{

private TextView timerValue;

private long startTime = 0L;

private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

SharedPreferences prefs;
String topspeed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceestate)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

this.onLocationChanged(null);

SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("values",     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String topspeed = prefs.getString("topspeed", "0");
TextView tv3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
tv3.setText(topspeed);
}




@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location p1)
{
TextView tv1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mainTextView1);

if(p1 == null){
tv1.setText("-.- mp/h");
}
else{
 float currentspeed = p1.getSpeed();
double mph_conversion = currentspeed * 2.2369362920544;

DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

tv1.setText(precision.format(mph_conversion) + " mp/h");

double topspeed1 = Double.parseDouble(topspeed);

if(topspeed1 > mph_conversion){
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("topspeed", Double.toString(mph_conversion));
editor.apply();
}
else{
TextView tv3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String topspeed = prefs.getString("topspeed", "0");
tv3.setText(topspeed);

}

}
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String p1, int p2, Bundle p3)
{
// TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String p1)
{
// TODO: Implement this method
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String p1)
{
TextView tv1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mainTextView1);
tv1.setText("Turn on high GPS accuracy");
}

private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

public void run() {


timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
int mins = secs / 60;
secs = secs % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
   + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
   + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}

};


public void bgcolour (View view){
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));

}


public void tv2click (View v){
//start timer
timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
 // This above line close correctly
}


}
```

Logcat error
03-09 20:57:29.690 E/AndroidRuntime(23288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: could you please post the logcat..

Comment: Contents of `SharedPreferences` object updated dynamically when you edit it. Don't reload it after saving - actually - try to not reloading it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `apply()` if you are going to be reading the stored preferences immediately.  Use `commit()` instead.  This call runs on the main thread, instead of the background like `apply()`, but you shouldn't notice any difference if you are just storing a little piece of data.  Here's more info on it.  [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit())

Answer (score 0):

You can't run these two lines before the constructor has been called on the Activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("values", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String topspeed = prefs.getString("topspeed", "0");
```

You would fix it by, for example, defining the vars here, but setting them in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Hi I changed my code like you said and it now stops the crash at the beginning and "0" shows up in the textview but when the GPS signal connects it crashes now.

Comment: I suggest posting a separate question for that, if you don't figure it out yourself.